# Perl qr// operation

Tags: perl

i have a question about Perl *qr* operator:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl -w
> &mysplit("a:b:c", /:/);  
> sub mysplit {  
>     my($str, $pattern) = @_;  
>     my @arr = split $pattern, $str;  
>     print "@arr\n";  
> }
> ```

The result is:

> Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at ./test.pl line 3.
>   Use of uninitialized value $pattern in regexp compilation at ./test.pl line 7.

But when i used: `&mysplit("a:b:c", qr/:/);`, it is ok.
So, i want to know what the difference between`qr//` and `m//`?
Why `$_` is related here?
And why it is ok in the case `split /:/, "a:b:c";`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, your problem here is that this expression:

```
/:/
```

really means this:

```
$_ =~ /:/
```

Which is why perl is reporting an uninitialized error on `$_`.

The `qr()` operator does not have this shortcut, which is why it by itself is an acceptable statement in this case.

So, to be clear: Your statement:

```
&mysplit("a:b:c", /:/);
```

Really means this:

```
&mysplit("a:b:c", $_ =~ /:/);
```

Since `$_` is undefined, the regex match returns the empty list. It *could* have returned the empty string, but since you have list context, it returns the empty list, making the error a little bit more obvious.

Because it returns the empty list, only one argument is passed to `mysplit()`, which is why you get the second warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value $pattern in regexp compilation at ./test.pl line 7.
```

If the empty string had been passed, this part of the error would have been silent.

Also, you should know that using ampersand `&` in front of your subroutine calls have a specific function. You should not use it unless you intend to use that function. The various ways of calling a sub are these, as documented in [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

```
NAME(LIST);  # & is optional with parentheses.
NAME LIST;   # Parentheses optional if predeclared/imported.
&NAME(LIST); # Circumvent prototypes.
&NAME;       # Makes current @_ visible to called subroutine.
```

The default way is the top one, in your case: `mysplit(...)`

Comment: ah... you are right! But why it is ok to use `split /:/, "a:b:c";` where no warning is popped?

Comment: Because `split` is implemented in such a way that you can do that. You can mimic such behaviour with prototypes, but I would not recommend it for beginners. There's really nothing to gain from it, IMO.

Comment: You might also consider such special cases as `pop @ARRAY` or `push @ARRAY, $foo`, which affect an array in a way that a subroutine would require a reference to do.

Comment: Another example is `map` and `grep`, where you can supply a code block with a stripped down syntax: `map { ... } ` instead of `map sub { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you very much, TLP! Thank you for the 'special cases' you mentioned. They are good cause i never came across Perl Prototype before:)

Comment: @rHao1116 You are welcome. Prototypes are difficult, poorly documented and -- in my opinion -- rather strange. I've never felt I needed them for anything, and I personally consider them mostly syntactic sugar.

Comment: If you never came across a prototype before, why are you prepending your function calls with `&`? Please get rid off that habit ASAP.

Comment: @TLP RE: *“Because `split` is implemented in such a way that you can do that. You can mimic such behaviour with prototypes”* The declaration `sub mysplit (/$$)` does not work—what prototype can I use to pass regexes without `qr//`?

Comment: @amon I'm not sure you can. Read more in perlsub: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes

Comment: Note that you also can't mimic block-less grep with prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $pattern in regexp compilation at ./test.pl line 7.
```

Is due to the fact you're failing to quote the the second parameter

```
&mysplit("a:b:c", /:/);
```

If you tried to print `$pattern` in `sub mysplit` you would see that it's an empty string.